# Find the limit in which constraints regard (ir)rationality.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> If
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x^2 \space\space\space\space \text{if $x$ is rational}\\ 
> 0 \space\space\space\space\space\space \text{if $x$ is irrational}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{f(x)} = 0$.

I don't know how to go about this proof. I imagine that for any tiny rational number $a$ near, there is a smaller irrational number, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you have $0 \le f(x) \le x^2$ for $\forall x$. Now think the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) for $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler: for any $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert<\varepsilon$, we have $0\le f(x)<\varepsilon^2 <\varepsilon$, whether $x$ be rational or irrational, if $\varepsilon <1$.