# Find the limit in which constraints regard (ir)rationality... again.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions, proof-verification

I recently posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019246/find-the-limit-in-which-constraints-regard-irrationality), and received an adequate answer.

However, I now have a similar question, which requires some verification.

---

### Exercise

> If
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0 \space\space\space\space \text{if $x$ is rational}\\ 
> 1 \space\space\space\space \text{if $x$ is irrational}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{f(x)}$ does not exist.

---

### Attempt

It seems like my proof that I used in my previous question is valid (which wasn't true for that one) for this one:

> For any tiny rational number $\delta$ near $0$, there is a smaller irrational number, and vice versa. Therefore, as $\delta$ continues to "shrink", $f(0 + \delta)$ will oscillate between $0$ and $1$.

---

### Request

**Is the proof above a valid solution?**

Answer (score 3):

To prove that the limit does not exist the easiest way to do this is by considering two different sequences that both approach $0$. Namely a sequence of rational numbers and a sequence of irrational numbers. The first will converge to $0$ and the other will converge to $1$.

Because two different sequences converging to $0$ had different $f(x)$ values, you have shown the limit doesn't exist.